# Flutter not reading device Developer Mode Setting

Tags: iphone, flutter, xcode, testing, ios17

I just upgrade to

```
Flutter 3.16.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b0366e0a3f (7 days ago) • 2023-12-05 19:46:39 -0800
Engine • revision 54a7145303
Tools • Dart 3.2.3 • DevTools 2.28.4
```

and I'm now unable to test on my iPhone connected via USB. I get the following message.

```
To use 'Scotts 14' for development, enable Developer Mode in Settings → Privacy & Security.
```

I have checked my phone and the Developer Mode is on. The only issue I have found talking about this is here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/111988 and I believe this is a Flutter fix back in Sept, 2022.

I'm running IOS 17.1.2 on my phone.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but after installing the iOS 17.2 platform from Xcode/Settings/Platforms, and upgrading the iPhone to iOS 17.2, the problem went away for me. Unfortunately not the only fix I tried, so I'm not 100% sure that this is what fixed it.

Answer (score 21):

I found the similar issue, although I did enable developer mode.

Here's how I fixed it:

1. Open Xcode while connecting your device, there should be popup asking you to Trust this computer.
2. Try running your app again.

Comment: confirming, after latest IOS update this helped!

Comment: Great! Works smoothly